# Subset a data frame in R based on above and below a threshold value

Tags: max, subset, threshold

I searched a lot to find similar post to my post below but no luck yet
I have 1 column of data like below (extracted from original big file having many columns)

```
C1 
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
3
3
2
1
```

From this data I want to generate a new column C2 where in C2 should just indicate where my C1 column values are above and below a threshold compared to max value. 
In this case max(C1) is 4.  So If set threshold of 2 then the new data should be like below.

```
C1 C2 
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  1
4  1
3  1
3  1
2  1 
1  0
```

Note: My data always have a increasing trend upto some point and then decreasing trend after that.
I know how to do  simple plain subset on a particular column but I am not getting the logic to subset when there is a increasing and decreasing trend.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the **plyr** package in r, and use an **ifelse** statement as a part of the **mutate** function. I will write my code and then explain. I assume you already have the **C1** vector in a data frame named **df**

> install.packages('plyr')
>
> library(plyr)
>
> df2 <- mutate(df, c2 = ifelse(c1 >= 2,1,0))

The mutate function creates a new column that satisfies whatever function you wish. In this case I used the **ifelse** function similar to excel's IF() function that inputs:

Condition **,** What happens if True **,** What happens if false.

Hope that helps =)

Comment: Dear Emby, Your code doesn't work for me in my particular case. However I got the answer to my question.